# Unified set of Eclipse Luna workarounds for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, redhat

I'm using a company-administered copy of Red Hat Linux, which means they push fixes out to me on a regular basis. Several of the recent fixes have caused Eclipse (any version) to blow up with an uninformative Java crash.

Websearching has been frustrating, since there are *several* incompatabilities which can cause this. In my system there appear to be two conflicts with some versions of Mozilla code, and one with the Cairo graphics library.

Now that I've got it working, I thought I ought to share what I'm using, to save others the searching and experimentation time. THIS IS NOT GUARANTEED, by any means, but it got me back on the air after some very painful thrashing.

***Late edit:*** I should have noted that when I was able to upgrade to Eclipse Mars, the crashes stopped occurring with the default configuration. So this is out of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to illustrate this is as a shell script. Note that much of it is commented out, but I wanted to leave those here as "notes" for things to try if this still doesn't solve your problems. In my case, suppressing GRE and Cairo was sufficient.

Note that the "NOCAIRO" switch could be moved into your exlipse.ini file... I preferred to keep it here so I wouldn't forget to apply it even if I switch to another copy/version of Eclipse.

I haven't written this to pass command-line arguments thru to Eclipse; that is left as a simple Exercise For The Reader.

One other thought: You may (or may not) want to add the -vm switch to your Eclipse invocation to have Eclipse itself run with a particular copy of the JRE. That too may help keep things stable if you upgrade your system with a newer version of Java.

Hope this helps someone...

```
#!/bin/bash
# Having some trouble running Eclipse on the latest Open Client for Linux?
# This front-end collection of kluges may help.

# Workaround for some other display bugs, not currently needed...?
# export GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=true

# Environment switch: Workaround for tooltip bug
export GRE_HOME=/DOESNOTEXIST

# Java switch: Workaround for Cairo breakage. 
# This could go into eclipse.ini
NOCAIRO=-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.cairoGraphics=false

# Java switch: Workaround for xulrunner breakage
#   There seems to be an open question about which versions work, if any.
#   Some suggest pointing to a specific 1.9 build, some suggest disabling.
#   I'm trying without that change for now.
# Something like this could go into eclipse.ini
#NOXUL=-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/dev/nul
NOXUL=

# Apply NOCAIRO/NOXUL switches from above
# Plus Joe's additional opts...
#   Show class and workspace name in Eclipse window header
eclipse -showlocation -vmargs ${NOCAIRO} ${NOXUL}
```